# AWS Wordpress Install - pages/posts 404 on restart until updating permalinks

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, 404-error, wp-config

I have launched a WordPress instance on AWS using elastic beanstalk. Every now and then AWS restarts my server and when it does all my pages/posts links switch to returning 404.

I can fix this by

1. logging into my instance through `/wp-login`
2. going to the `/options-permalinks` page
3. hitting [save changes] (without making any changes)

I am wondering if there is something I can add to my wp-config.php (or similar) to do the same work at launch every time so that I don't have a broken website randomly sitting there waiting for me to notice?

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: That's probably [`wp rewrite flush`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/rewrite/flush/) if you can set up wp-cli to run that on deploy, and I guess it's the .htaccess changes that are getting rewritten. So you could also make sure your instance template has the correct .htaccess, or update that on deploy. But no, this wouldn't go in wp-config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was based off the comment from @Rup on the question.  I needed to add a `.htaccess` file to my source.  I did this with the default contents:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

which I got from here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Adding this at the root of my deploy package (uploaded source) and the problem went away.